# How to access one function's variable in another function in Extjs4?

Tags: function, extjs, extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I have a view with checkboxes. In a controller I have written a function to get these checkbox values.

```
chekfeature: function (cmp) {
    cmp.mon(cmp.getEl(), 'click', function (event, target) {
            getFeatureId = target.id;
            console.log(getFeatureId);
            return getFeatureId;
        }, this, {
            delegate: 'input'
        });
},
```

So I'm getting the checkboxes values in getFeatureId. I want to access this variable in another function of same controller. I tried this:

```
getFeature:function()
{
     $getvalue = this.chekfeature();
}
```

But that's not working. So how do I access one functions variables in another function?

Comment: You can try using a global variable.

Comment: sir can you please elaborate same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, I think you need to look at some javascript basics...Then if you get that, have a look sencha's examples and tutorials.

In a view you have checkbox components.

In the controller you listen for the [change event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field)

If you have another function in the controller where you need that value, you pass it as a variable, to the function where you need it (=basic javascript) or you get the checkbox component and call the [getValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getValue) method.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/fDces/

```
//Defining a Controller
Ext.define('AM.controller.Pizza', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            },
            'checkbox': {
                change: this.onCheckChange
            },
            'button[action=orderPizza]' : {
                click: this.onOrderPizza
            }
        });
    },

    onCheckChange: function (checkbox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        console.log(newValue ? 'you checked ' + checkbox.boxLabel : 'you unchecked ' + checkbox.boxLabel);
    },

    onOrderPizza: function(button, e, eOpts){
        var checkboxes = button.up('form').query('checkbox');
        Ext.each(checkboxes, function(chk){
            console.log(chk.boxLabel +  ': ' + chk.getValue());
        });
    },

    onPanelRendered: function () {
        console.log('The panel was rendered');
    }
});
//Defining a View
Ext.define('AM.view.CheckForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.checkform',

    title: 'Choose toppings',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            fieldLabel: 'Toppings',
            defaultType: 'checkboxfield',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Anchovies',
                name: 'topping',
                inputValue: '1',
                id: 'checkbox1'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Artichoke Hearts',
                name: 'topping',
                inputValue: '2',
                checked: true,
                id: 'checkbox2'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'Bacon',
                name: 'topping',
                inputValue: '3',
                id: 'checkbox3'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Order',
            action: 'orderPizza'
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
//Creating the application
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',

    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: ['Pizza'],

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'checkform'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkfeature` function is not returning anything. You're in fact returning from the event handler function inside `checkfeature`.

You've got to question your execution flow here: knowing that you'll know the value of `getFeatureId` only after the component has been clicked, you can't call `getFeature` anytime you want. You need to wait for the click to happen, and go on from there.

Concretely, you need to wrap the processing you want to put in `getFeature` in a callback that will be executed **after** the user has clicked on the component.

Here's how to do it:

```
checkFeature: function(cmp, callback) {
    cmp.mon(cmp.getEl(), 'click', function(event, target) {

        // you most use var with your local variables and
        // avoid messing up or depending on the global namespace
        var featureId = target.id;

        console.log(featureId);

        // fires the callback
        callback(featureId);

        // do not return from the event handler because this result
        // will be interpreted by the event manager (i.e. in many 
        // cases, returning false from an event handler will stop
        // the processing that fired the event)
    });

    // see, there's no return here
}
```

Here's how you would use this method:

```
getFeature: function() {
    this.checkFeature(function(featureId) {
        // featureId is available here
    });

    // unfortunately, you won't be able to return something
    // depending on featureId from here... if you need to do so,
    // you'll have to use another callback in this method.
}
```

For simplicity's sake, in this example I execute the callback with a simple call. However, when using this pattern, it is usually a good idea to provide support for the execution scope of the function.

That is, here's how you should usually do it (this construct is omnipresent in Ext's code, as well as other libs):

```
function myAsyncFunction(callback, scope) {
    // example results you want to pass 
    var result = 1,
        result2 = 2;

    // execute the callback in the given scope, or default
    // to the current `this`
    callback.call(scope || this, result, result2);
}
```

Usage:

```
// let's say we are in the context of an object method
var that = this; 
myAsyncFunction(function(result, result2) {
    console.log(this === that); // true
}, this);
```

Comment: That said, VDP is right, what you're trying to achieve should probably not done this way. You should start your processing from the event handler function, and continue synchronously from there.